# "Dynamic" column selection

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

The problem:
The input table, let's say, is a merged table of calls and bills, having columns: TIME of the call and months of all the bills. The idea is to have a table that has the last 3 bills the person paid starting from the time of the call. That way putting the bills in context of the call.

The Example input and output:

```
# INPUT:
# df
# TIME        ID   2019-08-01   2019-09-01   2019-10-01   2019-11-01   2019-12-01
# 2019-12-01  1    1            2            3            4            5
# 2019-11-01  2    6            7            8            9            10
# 2019-10-01  3    11           12           13           14           15

# EXPECTED OUTPUT:
# df_context
# TIME        ID   0     1     2
# 2019-12-01  1    3     4     5
# 2019-11-01  2    7     8     9
# 2019-10-01  3    11    12    13
```

EXAMPLE INPUT CREATION:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['2019-12-01','2019-11-01','2019-10-01'],
    'ID':   [1,2,3],
    '2019-08-01':   [1,6,11],
    '2019-09-01':   [2,7,12],
    '2019-10-01':   [3,8,13],
    '2019-11-01':   [4,9,14],
    '2019-12-01':   [5,10,15],
})
```

The code I have got so far:

```
# HOW DOES ONE GET THE col_to FOR EVERY ROW?
col_to = df.columns.get_loc(df['TIME'].astype(str).values[0])
col_from = col_to - 3

df_context = pd.DataFrame()
df_context = df_context.append(pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, col_from : col_to].values))
df_context["TIME"] = df["TIME"]
cols = df_context.columns.tolist()
df_context = df_context[cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]]
df_context.head()
```

OUTPUT of my code:

```
# OUTPUTS:
#   TIME        0   1   2
# 0 2019-12-01  2   3   4    should be  3     4     5
# 1 2019-11-01  7   8   9    all good
# 2 2019-10-01  12  13  14   should be  11    12    13
```

What my code seems to lack if a for loop or two, for the first two lines of code, to do waht I want it to do, but I just can't believe that there isn't a better a solution than the one I am concocting right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps so that you can avoid dynamic column selection altogether.

1. Convert the wide table (reference date as columns) to a long table (reference date as rows)
2. Compute the difference in months between time of the call `TIME` and reference date
3. Select only those with `difference >= 0` and `difference < 3`
4. Format the output table (add a running number, pivot it) according to your requirements

```
# Initialize dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['2019-12-01','2019-11-01','2019-10-01'],
    'ID':   [1,2,3],
    '2019-08-01':   [1,6,11],
    '2019-09-01':   [2,7,12],
    '2019-10-01':   [3,8,13],
    '2019-11-01':   [4,9,14],
    '2019-12-01':   [5,10,15],
})

# Convert the wide table to a long table by melting the date columns
# Name the new date column as REF_TIME, and the bill column as BILL

date_cols = ['2019-08-01', '2019-09-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-12-01']
df = df.melt(id_vars=['TIME','ID'], value_vars=date_cols, var_name='REF_TIME', value_name='BILL')

# Convert TIME and REF_TIME to datetime type
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['REF_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REF_TIME'])

# Find out difference between TIME and REF_TIME
df['TIME_DIFF'] = (df['TIME'] - df['REF_TIME']).dt.days
df['TIME_DIFF'] = (df['TIME_DIFF'] / 30).round()

# Keep only the preceding 3 months (including the month = TIME)
selection = (
    (df['TIME_DIFF'] < 3) &
    (df['TIME_DIFF'] >= 0)
)

# Apply selection, sort the columns and keep only columns needed
df_out = (
    df[selection]
    .sort_values(['TIME','ID','REF_TIME'])
    [['TIME','ID','BILL']]
)

# Add a running number, lets call this BILL_NO
df_out = df_out.assign(BILL_NO = df_out.groupby(['TIME','ID']).cumcount() + 1)

# Pivot the output table to the format needed
df_out = df_out.pivot(index=['ID','TIME'], columns='BILL_NO', values='BILL')
```

Output:

```
BILL_NO         1   2   3
ID  TIME            
1   2019-12-01  3   4   5
2   2019-11-01  7   8   9
3   2019-10-01  11  12  13
```

Comment: Hi, this returns me the following error `Length of passed values is 9, index implies 2` when the `df_out = df_out.pivot(index=['ID','TIME'], columns='BILL_NO', values='BILL')` is run

Comment: Maybe it's because I am using pandas 0.23

Comment: fixed it by using `pd.pivot_table(df_out, index = ['ID','TIME'], columns = 'BILL_NO', values = 'BILL')` in my case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (newbie's) solution, it's gonna work only if the dates in column names are in ascending order:

```
# Initializing Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
'TIME': ['2019-12-01','2019-11-01','2019-10-01'],
'ID':   [1,2,3],
'2019-08-01':   [1,6,11],
'2019-09-01':   [2,7,12],
'2019-10-01':   [3,8,13],
'2019-11-01':   [4,9,14],
'2019-12-01':   [5,10,15],})


cols = list(df.columns)
new_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["0","1","2"])
# Iterating over rows, selecting desired slices and appending them to a new DataFrame:

 for i in range(len(df)):
    searched_date = df.iloc[i, 0] 
    searched_column_index = cols.index(searched_date)
    searched_row = df.iloc[[i], searched_column_index-2:searched_column_index+1]
    mapping_column_names = {searched_row.columns[0]: "0", searched_row.columns[1]: "1", searched_row.columns[2]: "2"}
    searched_df = searched_row.rename(mapping_column_names, axis=1)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, searched_df], ignore_index=True)
new_df = pd.merge(df.iloc[:,0:2], new_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
new_df
```

Output:

```
     TIME      ID   0   1   2
0  2019-12-01   1   3   4   5
1  2019-11-01   2   7   8   9
2  2019-10-01   3  11  12  13
```

Anyway I think @Toukenize solution is better since it doesn't require iterating.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but @Toukenize's answer can be easier implemented onto a different dataframe structure. :)